# Placing text after a certain amount of query results

Tags: php, html, laravel

Im running a query to bring back products from my database on a search page... here is what i want to do:

-I want to place some text after 6 and 12 of the 18 paginated results on each page.

-If a search is ran and less than 12 results come back, i want to show the text after 6 only

how would i go about doing this? here is my code.

html:

```
    @foreach ($products as $product)



                <div class="row sing">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"><div class="img"><div class=" container img-s" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/' . $product->image)}}'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center center;"></div></div></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="info-productsearch">
                    <div class="name-holder">
                    <h4>{{$product->productname}}</h4>
                        @if(Count($product->reviews) >0)
                        <p>Rated : {{number_format($product->reviews->avg('ratings'),2)}}/ 5, from {{$product->reviews->count()}} reviews</p>
                        @else
                            <p>Rated : Yet To Be Reviewed</p>


                        @endif

                    </div>

                    <p class="location-det"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> {{$productt->producttypes}}, {{$sight->productrefcode}}</p>
                    <p>{{substr(strip_tags($product->prodinfo), 0, 325)}}<a class="find-out-more" href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"> (...Find out more)</a></p>
                </div>
                </div>


    </div>
    @endforeach
```

I want to add in the explained above:

```
<div class="row text-center">
<h2> example</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `@for` loop, example :

`@for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++)
    @if (in_array($i,array(6,12,18)) && count($products) >= 12)
      Your action
    @elseif ($i == 6 && count($products) < 12)
      Your second action
    @endif
@endfor`

If I correctly understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have time to check, but it will be something like

```
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        @if (count($products) < 12)
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++)
                @if ($i == 6)
                    <div class="row sing">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"><div class="img"><div class=" container img-s" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/' . $product->image)}}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"></div></div></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="info-productsearch">
                                <div class="name-holder">
                                    <h4>{{$product->productname}}</h4>
                                    @if(Count($product->reviews) >0)
                                        <p>Rated : {{number_format($product->reviews->avg('ratings'),2)}}/ 5, from {{$product->reviews->count()}} reviews</p>
                                    @else
                                        <p>Rated : Yet To Be Reviewed</p>=
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <p class="location-det"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> {{$productt->producttypes}}, {{$sight->productrefcode}}</p>
                                <p>{{substr(strip_tags($product->prodinfo), 0, 325)}}<a class="find-out-more" href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"> (...Find out more)</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
             @endfor
        @else
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++)
                @if ($i == 6 || $i ==12)
                    <div class="row sing">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"><div class="img"><div class=" container img-s" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/' . $product->image)}}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"></div></div></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="info-productsearch">
                                <div class="name-holder">
                                    <h4>{{$product->productname}}</h4>
                                    @if(Count($product->reviews) >0)
                                        <p>Rated : {{number_format($product->reviews->avg('ratings'),2)}}/ 5, from {{$product->reviews->count()}} reviews</p>
                                    @else
                                        <p>Rated : Yet To Be Reviewed</p>=
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <p class="location-det"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> {{$productt->producttypes}}, {{$sight->productrefcode}}</p>
                                <p>{{substr(strip_tags($product->prodinfo), 0, 325)}}<a class="find-out-more" href="{{route('products.single',$product->slug)}}"> (...Find out more)</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
           @endfor
        @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where does my current foreach fit into this?

Comment: I edited the answer including your foreach loop. I did not have time to test it, but it should be something like this.

Comment: This isnt what i want man, I am entering text after the example code. The for loop should enter a <h2>example</h2> between the entries at 6 and 12 .  The edit doesnt do that.